# Cassandra on s390x architecture

Tags: cassandra

I have been trying to install Cassandra server on  a s390x machine, but I keep encountering setbacks along the way.

Do you know if there is official support for Cassandra for s390x architecture? I have  been looking on the official website but I could not find anything useful.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Here is the link on how to build Apache Cassandra for z Systems - [Building Apache Cassandra](https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/docs/wiki/Building-Apache-Cassandra)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not although Java should run everywhere. The thing is, C*/JVM won't utilize the amazing hardware you have there. Scylla on the other hand, has production workloads on s390 and was tested with 384 processors on a single machine: 
https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/new-ibm-linux-only-mainframe-delivers-breakthrough-security-for-next-gen-applications-300517548.html